# Flyway:migrate migrates correctly. but in the schema_version table the scriptname is prefixed with a /

Tags: flyway

select "script" from "schema_version";

O/P is:

```
/V0002__TEST.sql
```

My Maven plugin is configured as below:

```
com.googlecode.flyway
flyway-maven-plugin
2.2.1
jdbc:oracle:thin:${db.user}/${db.password}@//${db.host}:${db.port}/${db.sid}
${db.user}
true

filesystem:${basedir}/${repositoryhub}/${migration.directory}
```

Why is the file name always prefixed with a forward slash?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug. Please file an issue including the values of the placeholders you use and the OS you run on.

Comment: Thanks Axel. I have raised a Bug Issue #639. I face the issue in Windows as well as Unix.